# Eek! I'm not receiving reputation changes in the top bar!

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar

Since about 4:00 or 5:00 PM Eastern Time, I have noticed that the top bar hasn't been giving me notices about my reputation going up. This is extremely bothersome, as I thrive on those little numbers in green boxes. Has anyone else noticed this, or is it some setting I made?

`<troll>`

Quick! Upvote all my questions and answers to further test this hypothesis!

`</troll>`

So I'm guessing that this was because I placed a bounty for 50 points, and I haven't dug myself out of that hole since placing the bounty, but I still think that I should be getting the notices

Comment: Can you hear me now?

Comment: Do ypu have some sort of rep debt to pay off? Bounty or downvote?

Comment: Ohhh. I did put out a bounty earlier today, that may be it

Comment: Bounties are deducted immediately from your rep, and are not refundable anyway.  If it's a bounty that's causing this, I think that's a bug.

Comment: @TheGrinch - I agree.

Comment: Oh no, it's a dupe. <going to find>

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well, that was fast. 24 seconds. Here's your cookie. *hands*

Comment: Always feel bad when posting new answer to question I later close as dupe. Feels wrong to me, so luckily I already hit rep cap today! (So ironically, no green numbers to me too ;))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, you're right. Voting to close as dupe

Comment: @AmalMurali too much time here sharpened my dupe finding skill to near perfection. :D

Comment: and @ShadowWizard I wouldn't feel bad; I got more rep from this question than you did from your answer

Comment: @scrblnrd3 yeah, 3 shiny points and still counting! ;) (BTW if you'll *accept* my answer, I *will* get +15 :D)

Comment: Yesss. Got the accept in 0 seconds after I was allowed to!

Comment: [Thanks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pS2PX.png)!

Comment: Anyway, the green updates are now showing up; I've gotten 50 rep since bountying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You placed a bounty of 50 points 42 minutes ago.

You will see green numbers again once you'll get more than 50, or after you click the Achievements icon thus "reset" its internal counter.

As it stands, the green number is ever optimistic, never being negative.

Comment: This must be right.  Earlier today, I received 2 downvotes and no notification.  Then I received an upvote and got a green "+6" box (-2 -2 +10).